# Suddenly only 'snap' directory is visible in root

Tags: directory

Suddenly, the only folder that I can see in `/root` is `snap`.
Notwithstanding, the blog that I have installed on the website keeps working.

[image: ls output]

Output of `ls -al /`:

[image: ls -al / output]

Comment: Probably you are not in "root" directory. Please, run the command `ls -al  /`

Comment: Shouldn't `cd ~` leads me to root directory? Anyway, this is what the command returns https://imgur.com/a/SAPpR3M

Comment: @2-D `/` and `/root` are different. `/root` is the home of `root` user while `/` is [root directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory). The directories in `/root` in the screenshot provided seems fine to me since `root` user is not the default user making it's `$HOME` being less frequently used (unless you work after gaining `root` privileges). Please [edit] your question and let us know what you expect and what's happening. Moreover, please try to directly copy and paste terminal output into your question. Pictures are slower to load and it's impossible to copy/search from them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between / and /root in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773219/difference-between-and-root-in-ubuntu) See [heemayl's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/773220) and [user506739's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/773399).

Comment: Thank you guys. I think the lack of sleep corrupted my brain last night.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the home directory of user root, which is `/root`. Use `pwd` to check your current directory.